# Select MIN day within each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, partition, rownum

I am trying to pull min day within each month/Year (it is not always the first) - and balance and account that is attached to that day

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT [ACCT10]
  ,[MyDATE]
  ,[BALANCE]
   rownum=row_number() OVER(
   PARTITION BY DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,MyDate),0),[ACCT10]
   order by MyDate asc
   ) FROM
   [Accounts]
   )
    SELECT [ACCT10]
    ,[MyDATE]
    ,[BALANCE]
   FROM ranked where rownum = 1
   FROM [Accounts]
```

DATA:

Current

| ACCT10 | MyDate | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X546785e | 1/1/2023 | 57200 |
| X546785e | 1/2/2023 | 57500 |
| X546785e | 1/5/2023 | 59050 |
| X546785e | 2/3/2023 | 57800 |
| X546785e | 2/4/2023 | 60500 |
| X546785e | 2/5/2023 | 61200 |
| X5s5485e | 1/2/2023 | 16500 |
| X5s5485e | 1/5/2023 | 16520 |
| X5s5485e | 1/6/2023 | 19800 |
| X5s5485e | 2/1/2023 | 15000 |

Desired

| ACCT10 | MyDate | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X546785e | 1/1/2023 | 57200 |
| X546785e | 2/3/2023 | 57800 |
| X5s5485e | 1/2/2023 | 16500 |
| X5s5485e | 2/1/2023 | 15000 |

Unfortunately, I am unable to use the EXTRACT command

Comment: I am unable to use the 'EXTRACT" command

Comment: What is your actual RDBMS?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: The query in the question is invalid - please edit the question with the corrected query. The rownum calculation seen above cannot allow 2 rownum = 1 in a single month. Please check that the result seen above relates to the corrected query. see https://shorturl.at/qETV1

Comment: I dont know how to fix it - thats why i was writing my question here..

Comment: I see, so I have added an answer below so it doesn't depend on a third party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basics of that query seem OK, it just needs some tweaking to correct the syntax:

```
WITH ranked
AS (
    SELECT [ACCT10]
        , [MyDATE]
        , [BALANCE]
        , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, MyDate), 0)
            , [ACCT10] ORDER BY MyDate ASC
            ) AS rownum
    FROM [Accounts]
    )
SELECT [ACCT10]
    , [MyDATE]
    , [BALANCE]
FROM ranked
WHERE rownum = 1
```